# Why when using the front facing camera does my face detection box move in opposite direction?

Tags: swift, xcode

Im using the Vision Framework to make a face detection app. The problem im having is when Im using the front facing camera the face detection box doesnt follow my face. When I move my face to the right the face detection box goes to the left and same thing when I move my face to the left the face detection box goes to the right. Why does this happen?

```
func drawFaceboundingBox(face : VNFaceObservation) {

    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -frame.height)

    let translate = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: frame.width, y: frame.height)

    // The coordinates are normalized to the dimensions of the processed image, with the origin at the image's lower-left corner.
    let facebounds = face.boundingBox.applying(translate).applying(transform)

    _ = createLayer(in: facebounds)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to  work finally. Had to change the transform to this:

```
func drawFaceboundingBox(face : VNFaceObservation) {

let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: -frame.width, y: -frame.height)

let translate = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: frame.width, y: frame.height)

// The coordinates are normalized to the dimensions of the processed image, with the origin at the image's lower-left corner.
let facebounds = face.boundingBox.applying(translate).applying(transform)

_ = createLayer(in: facebounds)

}
```